# How to prevent duplicate values in circular stack?

Tags: python, stack

This is my code for my circular stack. I want to ensure that a user cannot enter a duplicate value into the stack.

```
CircularStack = [None] * 10
headPosition = tailPosition = 0

def AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, NewItem, headPosition):
    CircularStack[tailPosition] = NewItem
    printQue(CircularStack)
    CircularLength = len(CircularStack)
    PlaceToChange = CircularStack[tailPosition] = NewItem
    DelOrAddItem = input("Do you want to delete an item?")
    if DelOrAddItem == "Y" or DelOrAddItem == "y":
        DeleteItemFromQueue(CircularStack, tailPosition, NewItem, headPosition)
    else:
        if tailPosition == len(CircularStack)-1:
            tailPosition = 0
            AdditionItems = int(input("Add Number to Queue"))
            if headPosition == tailPosition:
                print("STACK FULL")
            else:
                AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, AdditionItems, headPosition)

        else:
            tailPosition = tailPosition + 1
            AdditionItems = int(input("Add Number to Queue"))
            if headPosition == tailPosition:
                print("STACK FULL")
            else:
               AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, AdditionItems, headPosition)

def DeleteItemFromQueue(CircularStack, tailPosition, NewItem, headPosition):
    if headPosition == tailPosition:
                print("STACK FULL")
    else:
        if headPosition == len(CircularStack):
            headPosition = 0
        else:
            headPosition = headPosition + 1
            AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, NewItem, headPosition)


def printQue(CircularStack):
    print(CircularStack)



FirstItemInQueue = int(input("Start Circular Queue with first input"))

AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, FirstItemInQueue, headPosition)
```

Comment: But doesn't this defeat the purpose of using a stack in the first place? The main selling point of a stack is that adding new values to it is O(1). If you have to first verify that the value doesn't exist in the stack already, then adding new items is O(N).

Comment: Sorry, my point is that I do not want to have to same value inputted into the stack twice. Is there any way of doing this easily?

Comment: Use a class to wrap the functionality together and sneakily store values into a set too, adding and deleting elements from the set as necessary. Provides fast lookup time but requires more storage than scanning the entire stack

Comment: @IanQuah, that sounds like a good suggestions however I am quite new to python and have never come across a set before. Could you please explain on how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
def AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, NewItem, headPosition):
    if NewItem in CircularStack:
        #item already exists; return without doing anything.
        return
    #rest of function goes here
```

Alternatively, loop until the value isn't in the list.

```
def AddingItem(CircularStack, tailPosition, NewItem, headPosition):
    while NewItem in CircularStack:
        NewItem = int(input("Item already exists. Please enter a different value: "))
    #rest of function goes here
```

Comment: This works but it complete stops the program, is there any way of doing this where it allows inputs to be added after the duplication of an input?